# Chart Zoom DotNet.HighCharts and WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, highcharts, zooming

Hi I'm doing a chart and need to put zoom in and observe at different distances and commute on it

not as placing the parameters for zoom

achieve obtain data from the database but that's the last part that I need to complete the project

asp.net

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Grafica.aspx.cs" Inherits="GraficaPrueba.Grafica" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server"> 
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

     <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
           <asp:Literal id="chrtMyChart" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </div>
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the data the get from this
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------...............................................................................................................................................

```
namespace GraficaPrueba
{
    public partial class Grafica : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection cn;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader dr;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Grafica_Chart();
        }

        public byte[] selectAlarmas(int idPAciente)
        {
            try
            {
                cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JAVIERCASASUC;Initial Catalog=FUCS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=pasante1;Password=sebastian1");
                cn.Open();
                Console.Write("conectado bien");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write("no se conecto" + e);
            }
            byte[] Datos = null;
            List<int> numeros = new List<int>();
            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ECG1 From dbo.Alarm where PatientiID=" + idPAciente + ";", cn);
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write("No se puede Consultar bien " + e.ToString());
            }
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    if (!dr.IsDBNull(0))
                    {
                        Datos = (byte[])dr.GetValue(0);
                        for (int i = 0; i < Datos.Length; i++)
                        {
                            numeros.Add(Datos[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return Datos;
        }

        protected void Grafica_Chart()
        {
            byte[] Datos = null;
            List<int> graficoY = new List<int>();
            Datos = selectAlarmas(104);
            Object[] chartValues = new Object[Datos.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < Datos.Length; i++)
            {
                chartValues[i] = Datos[i];
            }


            // Declare the HighCharts object    
            DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart").InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Line })
            //DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart2 = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart").InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = })    
                .SetSeries(new[]
                        {
                        new Series
                        {
                            Name = "ECG1",
                            Data = new Data(chartValues)   // Here we put the dbase data into the chart    

                        },
                    });


            chrtMyChart.Text = chart.ToHtmlString(); // Let's visualize the chart into the webform.

        }



    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard for me to understand what exactly is your question. Zooming fires [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.events.setExtremes) event on axis - you could trigger your code from there.

Comment: I want to do something like this example   http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line

Comment: The wrapper you are using for .net is not supporting Highstock - http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/workitem/303. You could try Highcharts official .net solution that supports Highstock - http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/197-highcharts-net